# Display laravel view in frontend after Fetch post request in React

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, fetch

I have laravel post api route with middleware auth:api that returns a view.

When I make fetch request in React as such

```
let coreUrl = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/core";
    let bearer = 'Bearer ' + data.access_token;
    await fetch (coreUrl, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json','X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest', 'Authorization':bearer},        
    })
    .then(response => {        
            console.log(response);
        }
    );    
  }
```

I receive response code 200 OK but user is still on same page not in returned view.
When I look under Network tab in chrome developer tools I can see that response contains that view but browser does not show it, instead remains on login page.
I also tried to switch method to get and then do redirect (api/core) instead of returning a view and this results in error too many redirects.

I tried also to create addittional get route and redirect user there, and then use window.location.href = response.url however this does not have bearer token with it and thus returns Unauthorized.

I wish to redirect user or display new view after login. How can I do that ?

In laravel I have this api route

```
Route::post('core', 'TripController@showCore');
```

In controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}

public function showCore() {
    return view('core'); 
}
```

So what Im thinking is if I make post request with bearer token I should see 'core' view? When I do this request with fetch in react response contains this view, how do I make this view to be displayed in browser?

This is a picture of where I'm at, post request response contains my view how can I display it?

[image: problem]

Comment: Why should the view change? You're neither telling the browser to navigate to that url (window.location.href) nor do you exchange your current DOM to contain the received data. So of course nothing happens. You're just fetching the data but do nothing with the results.

Comment: @CShark how do I use the view (laravel blade) inside response and get it to display? Im quite new to backend - frontend development and thus far Ive only needed to deal with json responses.

Comment: Honestly, I have never heard of laravel :D so I can't help you with that. I only saw that you didn't do anything with/after the response.